# Complex polynomial and P-type of extremum.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

I'm having trouble finding a simple example for below definition:

> For $P(x)\in \mathbb{C}[x]$, a complex number $c$ is said to be an extremum if $P(x)-c$ has multiple roots. The $P$-type of $c$ is defined to be the tuple $(\alpha _1,\ldots ,\alpha _s)$ of the multiplicities of the distinct roots of $P(x)-c$ in an increasing order. Obviously, $s<\deg P(x)$ and $\alpha _1+\cdots +\alpha _s=\deg P(x)$.

Is this a normal extremum? Could you please provide me a examples to this definition?

Comment: How do you define a normal extremum for a map that takes complex values?

Comment: For a real polynomial, the definition means that a P-type extremum is the value of $P(x)$ at a critical point, which includes both local extrema and inflection points. The definition extends to complex polynomials, though the intuition of an "extremum" may not. For example, if $P(x) = x^2 + 2i$ then $c=P(0)=2i$ is an "*extremum*" of P-type $(2)$ since $P(x)-2i=x^2$ has a double root $x=0$.

Comment: Thank you @dxiv for simple example.